# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input for particles.js

Tags: javascript, html, particles.js

I am getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input on line 36 when working with particles.js.
Code: https://jsfiddle.net/30qtvprj/
Main issue part of the code (where the error is triggered):

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", resp);
var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats();
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
stats.domElement.style.left = "0px";
stats.domElement.style.top = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector(".js-count-particles");
update = function() {
  stats.begin();
  stats.end();
  if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your jsonstuffs needs to be an object like so:

```
var jsonstuffs = {

  setData: function (key, obj) {
    var values = JSON.stringify(obj);
    localStorage.setItem(key, values);
  },

  getData: function (key) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) != null) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },

  updateDate: function (key, newData) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) != null) {
      var oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      for (keyObj in newData) {
        oldData[keyObj] = newData[keyObj];
      }
      var values = JSON.stringify(oldData);
      localStorage.setItem(key, values);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```